# Django - Order and filter on Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

What is the proper way to order and filter on a ForeignKey key on model like this one?

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def current(self):
        return TicketUpdate.objects.filter(ticket=self.id).first()

class TicketUpdate(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUSES, default='N')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES, default='N')
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITIES, default='D')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_time']
```

Every ticket has one (at least) or more TicketUpdate related.

I want to:

- list all the ticket from Ticket and show their current status (the newest TicketUpdate item)
- order the list by **TicketUpdate__created_time** or **Ticket__created_time**
- filter the list by **TicketUpdate__priority** or **TicketUpdate__type** or **TicketUpdate__status**

I am not sure if I have to make a Queryset on Ticket or on TicketUpdate.

I am not even sure if I need that **current()** function on the Ticket model: I use it on my ListView to retrieve the TicketUpdate info.

With

```
Ticket.objects.all().order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')
```

I get a list ordered but with too many entries.

Everything must run on a sqlite3 db too.

**Edit:**
This filter queryset

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='New').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')
```

return all the existing ticket, since all of them have an initial New status. I keep the whole history of a ticket: **New**, **Working**, **Fixed**, **NotFixed**, **Working** ("Working" again: that fix did not work and the user reopen the ticket)

So I want to filter just by the latest status: I need all the **Working** but what if a ticket have both Working and Fixed? I just need to filter on the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you don't really need that current method.

You could just get the queryset and take the first item;

```
Ticket.objects.all().order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')[0]
```

Or take a more django based approach of;

```
Ticket.objects.all().latest('ticketupdate__created_time')
```

And if you want to filter things;

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='status').order_by(
    'ticketupdate__created_time')

Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__priority='high').latest(
    'ticketupdate__created_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

For list all the ticket from Ticket and show their current status (the newest TicketUpdate item):

For List:

```
Ticket.objects.values('name', 'ticketupdate__status')
```

For latest Ticket Update Object:

```
TicketUpdate.objects.latest('ticket__created_time')
```

For ordering the list by TicketUpdate__created_time or Ticket__created_time:

```
Ticket.objects.values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')
```

or

```
Ticket.objects.values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('created_time')
```

For filtering the list by TicketUpdate__priority or TicketUpdate__type or TicketUpdate__status:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='your status choice').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time') # simillary priority
```

**EDIT**

As I can see, `status` field in the `TicketUpdate` is a Character Field, so that A TicketUpdate object can't have both `Working` or `New` Status. If you want to get the object which was lastly updated/created, consider adding [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) to field `created_time` and whenever you query using:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='New').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')
```

You will get the list sorted in such order that the last updated/created object will be the first index of that list. Also:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='New').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time').first()
```

Will return the latest `Ticket` data.

Comment: Tnx but your latest queryset is too open.Let's say I want to see all the tickets that are still "New" but not the other already "Fix":
**Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='New').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time')** will return all the existing tickets, since all of them initially have a New status.
I believe your queryset is: "give me all the tickets with a ticketupdate relation and in that relation its ticketupdate.status is New". But I need "give me all the tickets with a ticketupdate relation and its **NEWEST** ticketupdate.status is New"

Comment: `Ticket.objects.filter(ticketupdate__status='New').values('name', 'ticketupdate__status').order_by('ticketupdate__created_time').first()` shall return the Newest value from the list @MarioSignorino

Comment: Check my updated answer. I hope it will answer your questions :) @MarioSignorino